How do you replace a flex cable soldered directly to the PCB?
Good evening, everyone. I am looking for advice and hope you can help me. I am repairing a PCB (first photo), but the white flex cable with 12 pins spaced 0.5mm apart was directly soldered to the tracks on the PCB. Due to the lack of a microscope, it is very difficult for me to solder accurately. Additionally, the white flex cable is not heat-resistant, which complicates things further. I have an ideal FPC connector for the flex cable (second photo), but the PCB is very small, making it challenging to solder it properly. Maybe I should look for connectors like the one in the third photo. What do you think?
P.S.: Sorry for any grammatical errors in my English; I'm still learning.




Why do you believe that soldering a 0.5mm pitch connector (and with 90-degree space limit) is any easier than soldering flat wires? You should look to get a cheap stereomicroscope and a fine 0.1-0.2 mm soldering iron with well controlled temperature, and just do plain soldering.

@Ale..chenski Any tips for soldering? I have a hard time scraping the copper tracks and I want to avoid burning the flex with the soldering iron. thanks for answering

A FPC likely with polyimide outer layers will be way more resistant to temperature than the same size wires, in any case

Use a sticky copper foil over the flex cable, it will prevent the plastic from overheating. And use more mildly-activated rosin-based flux, and even more flux, and everything will be just fine.

The hardest part is holding the cable and circuit board in place so there is no movement. You might make a simple jig using a piece of wood and a router (rotary tool, not network device ;-) or just use adhesive tape and map pins to hold both parts to the wood. If the cable has solid-conductor wire, it should be simple to use fine-tip tweezers to align the stripped end of each wire parallel to the traces.
Use a fine-tipped soldering iron, and magnifying eyeglasses or lamp with magnifier.
Tin the ends of the cable and the traces before soldering.
Use fine, eutectic tin/lead, rosin core solder.
A quick touch of the iron tip to each wire should make the connection in under one second, before cable insulation melts.
Rest forearm on table to steady hands.
With a bit of practice, soldering 0.5 mm is possible.
Of course, expect the occasional solder bridge between traces. Use a solder wick (braid) or solder pump to remove extra, and reflow -- or for a really small bridge, use a sharp model-making knife to cut it.
